# Must iTune icon and app icon the same in design?

Tags: iphone

I would like to know if Apple has a rule that states the icon shown in iTune (512x512) must be of same design as the icon used in the applicaton (57x57)?

If they are not the same, will Apple reject the submission? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HI

Yes of course they have to be the same.You can refer the Itunes Connect Developer guide for further details

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will have to redo it before submission.